# Proving $\cos\left(x\sqrt{y^2 + 1}\right) < -\frac{y^2}{y^2+2}$, for $x\geq\pi/2, y > 0$, and $\pi>x\sqrt{y^2 + 1}$

Tags: inequality, trigonometry

I want to prove that the following inequality,

\begin{equation}
\cos\left(x\sqrt{y^2 + 1}\right) < -\frac{y^2}{y^2+2},
\end{equation} holds for all $x,y$ where $x \geq \frac{\pi}{2}, y > 0$, and $\pi>x\sqrt{y^2 + 1}$.

I've only checked the inequality numerically and know that it's true, but not quite sure how to prove it.

Any advice or proof would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We rewrite the problem, with a new variable $w=x\sqrt{y^2+1}$ instead of $y$.
So we want to prove that
$$ \cos w < -1 +\frac{2x^2}{w^2+x^2}$$
given that $ \frac12 \pi \leqslant x<w<\pi$.

---

Now note that for $\tfrac12\pi\leqslant w <\pi$ we have $\cos w\leqslant 1-\frac2{\pi}w$. (Proof: sketch a graph.)

And so it remains to prove that
$$1-\frac2{\pi}w<-1+\frac{2x^2}{w^2+x^2}$$
$$2\pi-2w<\frac{2\pi x^2}{w^2+x^2}$$
$$(w^2+x^2)(\pi-w)<\pi x^2$$
$$\pi w^2-w^3-wx^2<0$$
$$\pi w-w^2-x^2<0$$
$$ -(w-\tfrac12 \pi)^2-(x^2-\tfrac14 \pi^2)<0$$
but both brackets are positive and so we are done.